# appending spaces between few columns exported to textfile

Tags: c#

I am using c# windows application to get data from database and display on datagridview and exporting to text file I want to append  empty spaces in few columns at the end. this is my code for  exporting to text file..

```
 if (obj == null || obj == Convert.DBNull)
                return "";

            // if string has no ','
            if (obj.ToString().IndexOf(",") == -1)
                return obj.ToString();

            // remove backslahes
            return "\"" + obj.ToString() + "\"";
        }

        private void ExportDatatviewToCsv(string iFilename, DataView dv)
        {
            // Open output stream
            StreamWriter swFile = new StreamWriter(iFilename);


            // Rows of Data
            foreach (DataRowView rowData in dv)
            {
                string[] colData = new string[dv.Table.Columns.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < dv.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    object obj = rowData[i];
                    colData[i] = GetWriteableValueForCsv(obj);
                }

                // Write data in row
             swFile.WriteLine(string.Join("", colData));
```

here I am removing spaces between two columns but I need  3 columns which needs to be of fixed length of 44...... column 17, column 19, column 21

```
            }

            // Close output stream
            swFile.Close();
        }
```

I need space between these column of lenght 44 each..

```
 ",Left(ISNULL([t_vrm], '')+'    ',44) " + // column 17
    ",left(ISNULL([t_zone_name],'')+'    ',44) " + column 19
    ",left(ISNULL([t_date_time_issued],'')+'    ',44) " column 21
```

Comment: You can use String.PadRight Method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If an .xml file will do, export the data to xml from the datatable that should be present holding the data from the datagridview.